# Using Mouse as Wiimote IR in Cemu Emulator

Tags: controllers, wii-u, wiimote

If anyone is familiar with the Cemu Emulator, it is a Wii U Emulator, and a pretty decent one at that. Similar to Dolphin, it allows emulating the console's controllers, as in, you can emulate the Gamepad, the Pro Controller, and the Wiimote... However, unlike Dolphin, Cemu does not *fully* emulate the wiimote, it only emulates the button presses, and not the motions nor IR. What I want is a way to use mouse as IR for wiimote.

To put it simply, I want to play Pikmin 3 with a mouse and a keyboard in Cemu and use those as virtual wiimote of sorts.

Here is a set of questions, if any of the following is answered, then the problem is solved:

1. Is there a way in Cemu to fully emulate wiimote as in Dolphin? (the answer is no, i'm pretty sure)
2. Cemu is closed-sourced, yet Cemu-Hook is a popular "hack" that overrides the behavior of cemu, so where can I start to develop my own hook into cemu to add a feature that I want? (the hard-way)
3. Is there anyway to separately emulate the wiimote? for example, vJoy is away to create a virtual controller, is there a similar vWiimote?, or again, a very technical and detailed manual of how the wiimote works so I can attempt to work on that? (the exact opposite of the question [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/237984/can-i-use-a-wii-motionplus-remote-as-a-mouse-in-windows-10))

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but I do have an alternate solution, one which you may have already looked into; using the gamepad touch controls for Pikmin 3 instead of a wiimote.

Advantages:

- use built in mouse control for gamepad touch, works very similar to wiimote point controls
- can use v joy controls in addition to built in controls for mouse
- easy to set up/use (especially assuming you already use v joy)

Disadvantages:

- Pikmin cursor doesn't follow mouse movements when not clicked, as that would be like the gamepad following your finger without it touching
- no way to upscale crappy gamepad graphics in Cemu (to my knowledge)